# How do I open Google Maps with fetched information from DataBase with PHP/HTML (?)

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, google-maps

I'm really wondering how I can open a page with the information I got below with a link to google maps.  The code below fetch the location to an user, and puts it inside of a table. So I thought it would be neat to be able to click on the location in the table and have it to open in google maps. I'm  not sure how to manipulate the information from PHP to work as an HTML link (?).

```
 <td><?php echo $row_User['location']; ?></td>
```

(https://www.google.com/maps/place/ ---Location name --- ) - Link to google maps.

Thanks!

Comment: Something weird like:

   `<td>
            <?php 
            $loc = $row_User['location'];
            
            echo '<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/$loc" </a>'   
            ?>
                                          </td>`

Comment: You can't echo a variable when using singlequotes. Use doublequotes if you want to echo a variable(or none, or concatenate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
<?php echo '<a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/'.urlencode($row_User['location']).'" >Location</a>' ?>
```